# Нужна ли запятая? Объясните, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Считаете ли вы себя патриотом? Что значит любить свою страну?
>   Патриотизм — это чувство долга перед родиной. К сожалению, не всем
>   людям он свойственен. Однако смело можно утверждать, что любой
>   настоящий патриот любит свою страну всем сердцем. Многие задавались
>   этими вопросами, исключением не стал и Борис Степанович Рябинин. Так,
>   автором в тексте поднимается проблема проявления патриотизма.

Нужна ли запятая в последнем предложении после слова "так"? Объясните почему да или нет.